# Where can I see my own flag list and their respective accept/decline status?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

Where can I see my own flag history (all the flags I've raised) and their accept/decline status?

I have searched the help center, and my user summary, but didn't find a link.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> [image: entah imoj disruption hear]

Click on the number next to "helpful flags".

Comment: -1 for a specific scenario.Say if its my first flag, and its not being accepted by moderators as helpful flag, or its been rejected/declined, then i wont have the link (helpful flag) In that case, how can i go to my flag page.

Comment: @SmrutiSingh You'll see "helpful flags  0" and anyway will have an ability to click it.

Comment: I already checked that... Ok, for testing lets create a dummy acccount and flag anything(either post or comment) and see whats happening

Comment: Some of these numbers look suspicious.

Comment: In 2016, the profile looks somewhat different from this screenshot, but the helpful flags link still exists. The catch is that it's on the Activity tab, not the Profile tab.

Answer (score 28):

On SO:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<user-id>
```

On Meta:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<user-id>
```

In my case, for example, `user-id` is: `1835379`

As @slugster mentioned, you can find this page by clicking the number next to the *"helpful flags"* label, in your user profile.
(In the *stats* category)

Comment: Or just go to your user profile and click on the number next to the *helpful flags* label.

Comment: @slugster but the _helpful flags_ link doesn't appear until you have at least one accepted flag. AFAIK Cerbrus's URL is the only way to get there for new users.

Comment: This link still works for me in 2016.

Answer (score 9):

On your user profile page, there's a listing for "helpful flags" (next to "stats") with a number next to it. Click the number.

If there's no number, then none of your flags have been actioned yet.