# Show moderator flags in activity summary on profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, flag-history

I could not find a place where I can see my own moderator flags. <del>I'm sure</del> [it exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262002/where-can-i-see-my-own-flag-list-and-their-respective-accept-decline-status) but the activity tab on the profile page would seem like the natural place for this -- where I can see my votes, comments, suggested edits etc.  Even <del>if</del> *though* there is another entry point somewhere, it is an odd omission to not have this information in the place where all other information is collected centrally.

[image: "Activity" tab on profile page, where it would make sense to have a "flags" sub-tab]

My immediate problem seems to have been that I had clicked the "less info" collapse box; there is not much to suggest that you need to expand the big ole "personal information" block to get to see your flagging activity (and even then, it's not necessarily intuitive that clicking on your helpful flags number will show you your flag history).

Comment: Honestly, I still don't understand why they go out of their way to make reviewing your previous flags so undiscoverable.