# Could we have sorting flags by categories?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, design

[image]

It would be good to add links each showing corresponding flags, I'd like to know which of my flags were declined, which are active, etc...

Comment: Over 213 thousand?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yeah, whats wrong with that?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom he doesn't have that many, to have that many would take longer than he has had an account for. He likes to put big numbers in his bugs/feature requests.

Comment: @lostsock I do, [even more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262002/where-can-i-see-my-own-flag-list-and-their-respective-accept-decline-status/262004#262004). I am member for 310 years, my grand-grand-father owned this account.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why they don't already have this, is because they don't want everyone going through their declined flags and then bitching about them being *"incorrectly"* declined on meta.

Comment: @lostsock While yes, that is annoying, we *do* want people to find their declined flags so they can learn why they were declined and potentially stop that behavior in the future.

Comment: This would be very useful indeed.

Comment: I don't think you're gonna get a link to comments by the way...

Comment: @TJ maybe only for declined?

Comment: @nicael Actually somewhere I'd read that comments are stored in some other repository and it's hard for someone to find the deleted ones... So I'm guessing there will be technical challenges regarding comments... not sure though...

Comment: Playing with chrome's "inspect element" I bet :)

Comment: Seems like a good idea. And you have awesome paint skills :p

Comment: @MarcoA. Firefox has one too: http://i.imgur.com/XnaSnTH.png

Comment: And no one noticed that I drew only **one** "link?" from **both** "declined" and "disputed" :) (actually I want each to have own link, plz :D )